# Remove Windows directory path with RegEx Expressions

Tags: regex, notepad++

I do not know which RegEx Expressions to use for the following example in Notepad++?

Before:

```
C:\Users\PedjaNBGD\Desktop\Nidza&nbsp;Bleja&nbsp;sve&nbsp;pesme\Altina&nbsp;Dzez\
C:\Users\PedjaNBGD\Desktop\Nidza&nbsp;Bleja&nbsp;sve&nbsp;pesme\28&nbsp;23&nbsp;-&nbsp;Nidza&nbsp;Bleja,&nbsp;Mare&nbsp;G&nbsp;&&nbsp;Gorki\
```

After:

```
Altina&nbsp;Dzez
28&nbsp;23&nbsp;-&nbsp;Nidza&nbsp;Bleja,&nbsp;Mare&nbsp;G&nbsp;&&nbsp;Gorki
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!... This post does not contain a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to go:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*\\([^\\]+)\\(\R)`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  .*        : 0 or more any character but newline
  \\        : a backsmash (have to be escaped because it is a special character in regex)
  ([^\\]+)  : group 1, 1 or more any character that is NOT a baskslash
  \\        : a backslash
  (\R)      : group 2, any kind of line berak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1$2        : content of group 1 and content of group 2
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Altina&nbsp;Dzez
28&nbsp;23&nbsp;-&nbsp;Nidza&nbsp;Bleja,&nbsp;Mare&nbsp;G&nbsp;&&nbsp;Gorki
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly as a separate document, but it does not work in html file.
[link](https://imgur.com/KaMGfZK)
[link](https://imgur.com/plzfGoB)

Comment: @SmekeriBezPrezimena: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52003080/edit) and add real test case. You haven't said it was within a HTML file.